# In expansion of $(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....+x^{27})(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....x^{14})^{2}$ . Find the coefficient of $x^{28}$

Tags: binomial-coefficients, combinations, binomial-theorem

I am not able to apply binomial theorem here

$(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....+x^{27})(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....x^{14})^{2}$ 
Please help me to find the coefficient of$ x^{28}$
Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: it is $224$ the searched number

Comment: Help me to solve Graubner

Comment: [multinomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multinomial_theorem)

Comment: Hint: $1+x+x^2+\dots+x^{27}=(1-x^{28})(1-x)^{-1}$

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It is convenient to use the *coefficient of* operator $[x^n]$ to denote the coefficient of $x^n$ in a series.

> In order to determine the coefficient of $x^{28}$  we obtain
>   \begin{align*}
> \color{blue}{[x^{28}]}&\color{blue}{(1+x+\cdots+x^{27})(1+x+\cdots+x^{14})^2}\\
> &=[x^{28}]\frac{1-x^{28}}{1-x}\cdot\frac{(1-x^{15})^2}{(1-x)^2}\tag{1}\\
> &=[x^{28}]\frac{(1-x^{28})(1-2x^{15}+x^{30})}{(1-x)^3}\\
> &=[x^{28}](1-2x^{15}-x^{28})\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{-3}{j}(-x)^j\tag{2}\\
> &=\left([x^{28}]-2[x^{13}]-[x^0]\right)\sum_{j=0}^\infty\binom{j+2}{j}x^j\tag{3}\\
> &=\binom{30}{2}-2\binom{15}{2}-\binom{2}{0}\tag{4}\\
> &=435-210-1\\
> &\color{blue}{\,\,=224}
> \end{align*}

*Comment:*

- In (1) we apply the *[finite geometric series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_series#Formula)* formula.
- In (2) we expand the numerator $(1-x^{28})(1-x^{15})^2$ and skip all terms with exponent greater $28$ since they don't contribute to the coefficient of $x^{28}$. We also apply the *[binomial series expansion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series)*
- In (3) we use the linearity of the *coefficient of* operator and apply the rule
  $[x^{p-q}]A(x)=[x^p]x^qA(x)$. We also apply the binomial identity
  \begin{align*}
  \binom{-p}{q}=\binom{p+q-1}{q}(-1)^q
  \end{align*}
- In (4) we select the coefficients accordingly.

Comment: +1 This is what I tried to do myself, but couldn't make it work. I stopped trying when Donald posted his solution.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen: Thanks for upvoting! :-)

Answer (score 11):

If we multiply out $(1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{14})^2$ but *don't* collect like terms yet, there will be $15^2=225$ terms, all with coefficient $1$ (and various exponents between $0$ and $28$).

Each of these $225$ terms can combine with exactly one of the terms of $1+x+x^2+\cdots+x^{27}$ to make $x^{28}$ -- except for $1\cdot 1$ which would need a $x^{28}$ term that isn't in $1+x+\cdots+x^{27}$.

So there are $225-1=224$ terms of $x^{28}$ to add up, giving $224x^{28}$.

Comment: Cute :-) ${}{}$

Answer (score 4):

Express is as a product of three factors $F_1,F_2,F_3$:
$$(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....+x^{27})(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+....x^{14})^{2}=(1+\cdots +x^{27})(1+\cdots +x^{14})(1+\cdots +x^{14}).$$
Make up a table of powers of $x$:
$$\begin{array}{c|c|lcr}
m& n & \text{$F_1$} & \text{$F_2$} & \text{$F_3$} \\
\hline
& 1 & 14 & 14 & 0 \\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
1 & 14 & 27 & 1 & 0 \\
& 1 & 13 & 14 & 1 \\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
1 &15 & 27 & 0 & 1 \\
& 1 & 12 & 14 & 2 \\
&\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
2 &15 & 26 & 0 & 2 \\
&1 & 11 & 14 & 3 \\
&\downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
3 & 15 & 25 & 0 & 3 \\
& 1 & 10 & 14 & 4 \\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
4 & 15 & 24 & 0 & 4 \\
& 1 & 9 & 14 & 5 \\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
5 & 15 & 23 & 0 & 5 \\
& \cdots & \cdots & \cdots & \cdots \\
& 1 & 0 & 14 & 14 \\
& \downarrow & \downarrow & \downarrow & \vdots \\
14 & 15 & 14 & 0 & 14 \\
\end{array}$$
Hence:
$$1\cdot 14 + 14\cdot 15=224.$$

Answer (score 4):

The coefficients are bounded by $28 \cdot 15^2 = 6300$. So the following 
[program](https://repl.it/K3dG/2) that uses Python 3.6 integer arithmetic can be used to  find the solution

```
x=(((6301**29-1)*(6301**15-1)**2)//6300**3)
y=x%(6301**28)
z=y//6301**27
print(z)
```

It prints out

```
224
```

*Python's operators:*

- = is the assignment operator
- * is the multiplication operator
- ** is the exponentiation operator
- % is the remainder operator
- // is the integer division operator

Comment: LOL! Another nice idea!

Answer (score 3):

\begin{eqnarray*}
(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots+x^{27})(1+x+x^{2}+x^{3}+\cdots+x^{14})^{2} \\
= (1+x+x^{2}+\cdots+x^{27}) (1+2x+3x^{2}+\cdots +14x^{13}+15x^{14} +14x^{15} \cdots +2x^{27}+ x^{28}) \\
= \cdots+x^{28}( \underbrace{1+2 +\cdots + 15}_{120} + \underbrace{14+ \cdots +2}_{104})+ \cdots 
\end{eqnarray*}

EDIT

[image]

Comment: so we can believe you or we don't believe you. I think some arguments that supports your calculations will be necessary.

Comment: @miracle173 Can you not follow the steps in a textbook multiplication of polynomials?

Comment: I think it would be more convincing without the screenshot, but to each their own I suppose :-)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I am very grateful for your help. I should have done the computer algebra first ? ... anyway third time lucky !

Comment: @miracle173 It is a miracle ? I might have got the right answer (or JL and DrSG did ?)

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I don’t know how polynomials multiply textbooks. But I see that for the terms $a_i x^i$ with small $i$ the equation
$a_i-i=1$
holds as expected and for large $i$ the equation 
$a_i+i=29$
holds in the second line, and so I trust in the result now. When I compare the second and the third line I see that it isn’t even necessary to calculate the coefficients of the product explicitly but the coefficient of $x^{28}$ is 
$(1+x+x^2+\cdots x^{14})^2|_{x=1}-1=15^2-1=224.$